# java mySQL Retrieve Point

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve POINT Blobs from MySQL and I'm having an issue decoding the data I receive from the query to a POINT object that I can use.

I use this code to retrieve the blobs from MySQL:

```
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = result.getMetaData();
        colCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
            fieldVector.add(metaData.getColumnName(i + 1));
        for (int i = 0; result.next(); i++) {
            resultVector.add(new Vector<Object>());
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
                resultVector.get(i).add(result.getBlob(j + 1));
```

The query is a string that calls for all the data in the table.

Now when I check the data on each vector, I see that it contains a field called `binaryData`.
But I cant understand how to interpret it to an actual X and Y coordinates
Maybe I'm missing something and there is an easier way, ill be glad to get some info about it.

Here are some BinaryData values and the actual point they should represent:

`0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 102, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 127, 64 
-POINT (179 497)
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -32, 103, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 126, 64
-POINT (191 485)
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -64, 101, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 125, 64
-POINT (174 470)
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 101, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 126, 64
-POINT (171 482)
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -64, 99, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 126, 64
-POINT (158 480)
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -64, 99, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -80, 125, 64
-POINT (158 475)
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 99, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -96, 125, 64
-POINT (154 474)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to my original question. 
but what I eventually did was changing the query to get the points coordinates as text by using the AsText() function in MySQL for each field and I created java Point from those.